# Open modal with button within the table

Tags: c#, asp.net, modal-dialog

I have created button in my cs file with the code as below, and try to fire the event handler for the button which inside the table. However, it does not function with it. May I know what should I do?

```
protected void feesinfo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Hidden field for checking in .aspx file
    ClientScript.RegisterHiddenField("typeButton", "FEE_INFO");
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("School Fees Details");
    Table tbl = new Table();

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {

        TableRow tRow = new TableRow();


        Table1.Rows.Add(tRow);

        for (int j = 1; j <= 6; j++)
        {
            TableCell tCell = new TableCell();


            if (j == 4)
            {

                Button btn = new Button();
                btn.CssClass = "btn btn-success";
                btn.ID = "btndetails";
                btn.Text = "400";
                tCell.Controls.Add(btn);
                btn.Click += new EventHandler(btnClick);

            }
            else
            {
                tCell.Text = "Row " + i + ", Cell " + j;
            }

            tRow.Cells.Add(tCell);

        }

    }
}

protected void btnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ClientScript.RegisterHiddenField("typeButton", "Details");
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("School Fees Details");

    mpe.Show();
}
```

Comment: have you tried setting the `Click` event, *before* adding it to the list of controls?

Comment: This will not make any difference. Look at a Designer.cs!

Comment: @TaW - Designer.cs won't help, the button is added dynamically.

Comment: I know. But it will tell you that the __order__ is not important! The designer adds the controls to the Contrals collection __after__ they have been completely defined, including events.

Comment: What platform? WPF? ASP? What is a Table?

Comment: Where is `mpe` declared and instantiated? It may be worth changing the debug string in `btnClick` so that its text differs from the debug string in `feesinfo_Click` so that you can be sure it is not firing correctly. Of course breaking will get you that too

Comment: @dumbledad mpe is declared in .aspx which my interface has been coded. which i actually refer to this site.

Comment: @dumbledad

http://blog.krisvandermast.com/ASPNETAJAXControlToolkitModalpopupextenderControl.aspx